# We can able to view docx files using Version control system GIT?

Tags: git, github

Using an **Version control system Git**. I have pushed some `docx` files into an Git repository.

Using an **GITLIST** to view `docx` files in the browser. When i click the docx files it shows an empty.

Please provide a solution to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Diff (and collaborate on) Microsoft Word documents using GitHub](http://ben.balter.com/2015/02/06/word-diff/)" by **[Ben Balter](https://twitter.com/benbalter)**:

> if you were to try to view a single commit to review what’s changed, due to Word’s black-box nature, the best you could get would likely be something like this:

[image: http://ben.balter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/binary-diff.png]

> That’s because, despite its widespread adoption, a Microsoft Word documents is, in reality, [a proprietary and purpose-built legacy format](http://ben.balter.com/2014/03/31/word-versus-markdown-more-than-mere-semantics/), and one that that’s especially hard to use outside of Microsoft Word. And that’s the exact problem Word Diff aims to sovle.

The same would apply to [**gitlist.org**](http://gitlist.org/) (GitHub project [`klaussilveira/gitlist`](https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist)).

The blog post suggests converting doc word into markdown using [WordDiff](https://github.com/benbalter/word_diff). That might be a workaroud to consider, depending on your case.